# Threejs: curved text, how to?

Tags: html, three.js

I'm working on Three.js trying to obtain an object with curved text.

Is the right way using TextGeometry?

```
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xdddddd
  });
  var textGeom = new THREE.TextGeometry( 'Foo', {
    font: 'helvetiker', 
    curveSegments: 10, 
    bevelEnabled: true
  });
  var textMesh = new THREE.Mesh( textGeom, material );
  scene.add( textMesh );
  textGeom.computeBoundingBox();
  textGeom.textWidth = textGeom.boundingBox.max.x - textGeom.boundingBox.min.x;
```

Comment: take a look at http://alexan0308.github.io/threejs/examples/#webgl_modifier_bend

Answer (score 0):

I thik the code is correct. You must load the font in your header with :

```
<script src="http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.js"></script>
```